# NextAuth Credentials returns null after successfully fetch data

Tags: null, next.js, return-value, next-auth

Currently I'm  having trouble implementing `next-auth` **credentials provider** into my system.

I'm using `axios` (**to a different localhost**) to *verify* the **credentials** (email & password).

- **Nextjs** system run in `http://localhost:3000`
- **Node Server** run in `http://localhost:5400`

#### These are **the problems** I'm currently facing:-

1. after **successful login**, I was **redirect** to `http://localhost:5400` (blank screen). This is true even when I `logout` from the system. it still redirect me to the same url.
2. even after **successful login**, `user` returns `null`. The only data I get from the `session` is `expires`

My current code now:-

- demo button to call `signIn` & `signOut`:-

```js
// in homepage (pages/home.js)
import { signIn, signOut, useSession } from 'next-auth/client'

export default Homepage = () => {
  const [ session ] = useSession()  
  console.log(session) 
  // returns 'null' (when not login yet)
  // returns { expires: "2021-06-28T08:59:47.504Z", user: { name: null, email: null, image: null, _proto_: Object }, _proto_: Object } after successful login  

  return (
    <>
       {!session ? 
        <>
          Sign-in to continue
          <button onClick={() => {
            signIn('credentials', 
            { 
              email: 'mohdfathi_mhdnoor@yahoo.com', 
              password: 'qwer1234', 
              callbackUrl: `${window.location.origin}/about` 
            })
            }}>SignIn</button>
        </> 
      :
        <>
          {session.user.email}
          <button onClick={() => signOut()}>SignOut</button>
        </>
      
      }
    </>
}
```

- `[...nextauth].js`:-

```js
import axios from 'axios'
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import Providers from 'next-auth/providers'
import { config } from '../../../src/utils/Header'

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    Providers.Credentials({
      name: 'Portfolio V4 Credentials',
      credentials: {
        email: { label: "Email", type: "email", placeholder: "Please enter an email" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password", placeholder: "Please enter a password" }
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        try {
          const res = await axios.post(
            process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_ENDPOINT_HOST + "/api/auth/callback/credentials", 
            { uid: '', email: credentials.email, password: credentials.password },
            config
          )
          const user = await res
          
          if (user.data.success) {
            console.log(user.data) // this logouts { success: true, data: { uid: '5f8fc26c6a103b243428bec1', sato: 1622295126589 } }
            return user.data
          }
        } catch (e) {
          console.log('Error: ')
          console.log(e)
          return null
        }
      }
    })
  ]
})
```

I did change the content of `user` to what I get from the `server`. But it didn't **reflect** at all what's in the `session` I `console.log` above. It still `console.log`:-

```
{
  expires: "2021-06-28T08:59:47.504Z",
  user: {
    email: null,
    image: null,
    name: null,
    _proto_: Object
  },
  _proto_: Object
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Next-Auth | When user object have too many items then session request is without data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68010914/next-auth-when-user-object-have-too-many-items-then-session-request-is-without)

Look at the code under that link. What you need is in the callback function.

Comment: I meant to upvote your answer and misclicked twice. If I forget comment back and I will upvote.